# React Native/Firebase: Issue with FlatList Re-Rendering & Duplicate Keys

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist, react-native-firebase

I am using React Native and Firebase Realtime Database. I am experiencing two problems with the `FlatList` component:

1. I am getting a lot of "duplicate key" errors whenever the list re-renders. I am not sure why I am getting this problem because I am setting the key of every item in my list as the `snap.key` value generated by Firebase, which is unique (and I have verified this in my logs).
2. The list sometimes does not re-render, even when I scroll up or down on it. This "sometimes" behavior is throwing me off, and I have not been able to debug it. I am using the ".on" method for getting my list from the Firebase Realtime Database.

This is the code that I am using:

```
export default class FlatListPage extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); 
        this.state = { 
            data: [],
        }; 
    }

    makeRemoteRequest = () => {
        var items = []; 
        DB.on('value', (snap) => {
            this.getItems(snap, items); 
            items = items.reverse(); 
            this.setState(
                {data: items}
            ); 
            console.log(this.state.data);  //checking key properties are unique 
        }); 

    }

    getItems = (snap, items) => {
        snap.forEach((child) => {
            items.push({
                key: child.key, 
                status: child.val().status, 
                location: child.val().location, 
            });
        });
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        this.makeRemoteRequest(); 
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <MyListItem item={item} />}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving duplicate keys because you're not resetting the `items` array when receiving a new `value` event from firebase.  This means you're simply re-adding the same items over and over again.

Update your `makeRemoteRequest` method to recreate the array each time you get a `value` event as follows:

```
makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    DB.on('value', (snap) => {
        var items = [];
        this.getItems(snap, items); 
        items = items.reverse(); 
        this.setState(
            {data: items}
        ); 
        console.log(this.state.data);  //checking key properties are unique 
    }); 
}
```

I'm not sure about number 2 - it might be that the above fixes it as a side effect.

Comment: Thank you! Good catch, it is functioning much smoother now and #2 was taking care of as a side effect.

If I wanted to clear the `var items' variable outside of the .on function, should I do so inside the lifecycle method componentWillUpdate()? I may have to add more data to it (using several .on connections), so I won't be able to place it inside any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

instead of getting the whole list every time I suggest to get all elements *.once* and then use 'child_added' event and *.limitToLast(1)* to get only new items and add them to your array. Also, I noticed that you are pushing items to the array and then reversing it. You can use *.unshift* method that inserts items at the beginning of the array so you do not have to reverse it later.